# How to share common module in two different set up of zend framework ?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have two different setup of zend framework some modules are common in the both set up so how can I access that commmon module in both the set up so i can manage both the module easily with only on one change please suggest me best solution for that

Answer (score 0):

If you're hosting both apps on the same machine and under Linux/UNIX/MacOS you can just [symlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) from the module dir in one app to the other.

This IS NOT an ideal solution. Better have this on your dev machine and deploy two copies of the source code.

If you are using [CI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) it'd be quite easy to manage this. But then again - the module may be the same however the different apps may have different settings and so on. You should be considering this very carefuly.

Comment: Hello Thanks for your reply but I have same server for the apps.

Comment: So what is the problem if it is on the same server? Symliniking would only work if the apps were on the same server...

Answer (score 0):

array(
        'Application',
        'DoctrineModule',
        'DoctrineORMModule',
        'Merchant',

```
),
'module_listener_options' => array(
    'config_glob_paths'    => array(
        'config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php',
    ),
    'module_paths' => array(
        './module',
        '../vendor',
        '../commonmodule(with that directory path)',
    ),
),
```

);